# android viewpager layout_behavior что значит?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, coordinator-layout

Увидел такой layout, что делает `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior`?

```
<"android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот атрибут указывает на класс, в котором описано как должен вести себя этот элемент, если он является прямым потомком `CoordinatorLayout`. В данном случае, значение `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` говорит о том, что этот элемент будет реагировать на события, генерируемые `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: Не совсем верно, данная связь не определяет поведение, а транслирует события (касания, прокрутки и тп.) из дочернего View в родительское

Comment: @pavlofff, ну, я отвечал в меру своего разумения)